# Extending background color of Div in Grid System

Tags: css, html, grid, skeleton-css-boilerplate

Note: I'm using the skeleton grid system.

I am looking to extend the background color of one of my divs to the right, past the 960px container, but I am having no success. Any suggestions?

Current:
[image]

What I'm looking for:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs
  ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Your Page Title Here :)</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  ================================================== -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/responsive-nav.css">


    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

<script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <!-- Primary Page Layout
    ================================================== -->

    <!-- Delete everything in this .container and get started on your own site! -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <h1 class="remove-bottom" style="margin-top: 40px">Skeleton</h1>
            <h5>Version 1.2</h5>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <h3>About Skeleton?</h3>
            <p>Skeleton is a small collection of well-organized CSS files that can help you rapidly develop sites that look beautiful at any size, be it a 17" laptop screen or an iPhone. It's based on a responsive grid, but also provides very basic CSS for typography, buttons, forms and media queries. Go ahead, resize this super basic page to see the grid in action.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column">
            <h3>Three Core Principles</h3>
            <p>Skeleton is built on three core principles:</p>
            <ul class="square">
                <li><strong>A Responsive Grid Down To Mobile</strong>: Elegant scaling from a browser to tablets to mobile.</li>
                <li><strong>Fast to Start</strong>: It's a tool for rapid development with best practices</li>
                <li><strong>Style Agnostic</strong>: It provides the most basic, beautiful styles, but is meant to be overwritten.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="one-third column" id="support">
            <h3>Docs &amp; Support</h3>
            <p>The easiest way to really get started with Skeleton is to check out the full docs and info at <a href="http://www.getskeleton.com">www.getskeleton.com.</a>. Skeleton is also open-source and has a <a href="https://github.com/dhgamache/skeleton">project on git</a>, so check that out if you want to report bugs or create a pull request. If you have any questions, thoughts, concerns or feedback, please don't hesitate to email me at <a href="mailto:hi@getskeleton.com">hi@getskeleton.com</a>.</p>
        </div>

    </div><!-- container -->


<!-- End Document
================================================== -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
* Skeleton V1.2
* Copyright 2011, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 6/20/2012
*/

/* Table of Content
==================================================
    #Site Styles
    #Page Styles
    #Media Queries
    #Font-Face */

/* #Site Styles
================================================== */

#support{
    color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of achieving this could be to add a new HTML element inside the `#support` and give it a 100% right padding and 100% negative right margin.  Like this:

```
<div class="one-third column" id="support">
  <div class="inner">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

#support .inner {
  padding-right: 100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Then add a 'page' container with overflow hidden to make sure you don't get a scrollbar.

```
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

#page {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

In the first step, the reason I added a new `<div>` rather than styling the existing `#support` is that I think it's best to leave `<div>`s that have grid structure styles alone.  We don't want to affect their margins.

**[Here's a demo](http://jsbin.com/aWeFoNuC/2/edit)**.